# Use of For _ in range()

Tags: python

I am a newcomer to Python, and I'm using anaconda/jupyter.
Have been unable to decipher the following error message:

```
sims=[500]
For _ in range(1000):
File "<ipython-input-264-b9c4f88d1aeb>", line 1
    for i in range(sims):
                         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

In know the meaning of EOF but cannot find he error.
Help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: There has to be something after `for i in range(sims):`. You can't end your code right there, the loop has to have something in it. For now you can just change it to: `for i in range(sims):pass`

Comment: For the 2nd loop you have no function/action to do each, and your first for loop should also be lowercase 'for'

Comment: and sims should be 500, not [500].

Comment: This will also error out due to `sims` being a list. `range` expects an int. remove the brackets around `500` and as others say, you need a statement after/within the lowest loop statement.

Comment: Also, `For` should have a lowercase `f`

Comment: Hi Raul, please consider clearly specifying your program and the results.  The way you have presented the question, it looks like you have the syntax error in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Considering the previous comments:

1. Your variable `sims` doesn't have to be a list because it is just a single number, or maybe you can call it later as `for i in range(sims[0]):`
2. Your code is finishing after that `for`, set `for i in range(sims[0]):pass` to let Python to know it is ending.
3. You have an uppercase in your first `For`, change it to `for`

Comment: Many thanks for the help received from several users. Problem solved now! Thanks again

Comment: Do not forget to chose it as a definitive answer, and remember to avoid using 'thanks' in the comments, giving up votes and declaring answers is the way of saying it. Welcome to the community!